# Proguard configuration for inner Interface

Tags: java, proguard

I have class with implements inner interface of another class like this:

```
public class DownloadService extends Service implements Downloader.Callback { 
    ....
    // override interface methods and other stuff
    ....
}

public class Downloader {
    private Callback callback;

    public Downloader(Callback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    ....
    ....

    public interface Callback {
        // interface methods
    }
}
```

Now, when I'm usning proguard on this code I'm getting warnings like this:

```
com.example.DownloadService$Downloader: can't find referenced method 'java.util.List access$000(com.example.DownloadService)' in program class com.example.DownloadService  
com.example.DownloadService$Downloader: can't find referenced method 'void access$100(com.example.DownloadService)' in program class com.example.DownloadService    
com.example.DownloadService$Downloader: can't find referenced method 'android.app.NotificationManager access$200(com.example.DownloadService)' in program class com.example.DownloadService
```

How do I fix this? I have tried adding the following to my proguard.cfg:

```
-keepclasseswithmembers class com.example.DownloadService { *; }
-keep public interface com.example.tasks.Downloader$Callback { *; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. `com.example.DownloadService$Downloader` is an inner class I've deleted recently. A *Build > Clean Project* fixed it.

4 hours of my life - just gone.